# jQuery FullCalendar combining JSON and GCAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I just download FullCalendar today and I've been trying to combine the JSON calendar with the gcal. In addition to my JSON data i would like to show national holidays too, can someone please tell me whether this is possible or not.

I've tried this and it's not working. thank you!

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },

        editable: true,

        events: "json-events.php",
                $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic'),


        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the [answer here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/eventSources/). I replace the events with eventSources. In case anyone else is look for the same thing.

```
eventSources: [
  "json-events.cfm",
   $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic')
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I use like this:

```
eventSources: [

    "json/events.inc.php",
     { url:'https://google.com/calendar/feeds/20929292',
       className: 'fc-event'}

]
```